# How can I abort installshield setup by c#?

Tags: c#, installshield, installshield-le

I use Install Shield 2013 limited edition. I do some configurations via an c# application `(customconfigs.exe)`. The c# application will be invoked in my custom actions:

[image: installshield custom actions]

There are some conditions defined in my c# application. When not match, I want to trigger aborting the setup and rollback. How can I tell InstallShield to abort the setup?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if(false)
    {
        //please abort setup
    }
}
```

Comment: End your c# program after you set `Environment.ExitCode=1;`?

Comment: That works. But how can I suppress or overwirte the text of the Error message?

Comment: okay, altering or suppressing the error message does´t work.